# How are components typically connected to a PCB when they are mounted in an enclosure?

Tags: pcb-assembly, enclosure

Many small speakers are designed with screw holes to mount them in enclosures.  They also have connectors to solder wires so they can be electrically connected to a PCB.  How do I do something similar with a photoresistor?  I want to mount a photoresistor (PDV-P8104 as a random example) in an enclosure, then connect the terminals of the photoresistor to wires and connect the wires to the PCB.  How does one typically connect the terminals of a through hole component to a PCB when the component must be physically placed farther away from the PCB than the length of the leads?

Answer (score 1):

Solder wire to it and the pcb. Heatshrink if needed. Or mount on a small pcb then use wires between the two. Or use connectors/headers on one or both sides. Or use crimps if acceptable.

Comment: And use twisted pair light gauge wire.

Comment: And add a cap for fluorescent lights.

Comment: By crimps, do you mean something like a "butt splice connector"?  That would be simple to implement.

Comment: @jeff sure if the butt connector is the right size for the lead you are crimping. Too large and it won't make a good strong connection. If vibration is involved even worse.